# how to make PHP lists all Linux Users?

Tags: php, linux, command-line, ubuntu

I want to build a php based site that (automate) some commands on my Ubuntu Server

first thing I did was going to the file (sudoers) and add the user www-data so I can execute php commands with root privileges!

```
# running the web apps with root power!!!
www-data    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

then my PHP code was

```
<?php
   $command = "cat /etc/passwd | cut -d\":\" -f1";
   echo 'running the command: <b>'.$command."</b><br />";
   echo exec($command);
?>
```

it returns only one user (the last user) !!! how to make it return all users?

thank you

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea for security reasons.

Comment: Will you tell us the address of your server afterwards? :-)

Comment: @Matt: yes I know, so what is the best approach to achieve such function?
@Alexander: the server located in a private net for testing and learning purpose, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP manual on exec:

> Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the
>   command. If you need to execute a
>   command and have all the data from the
>   command passed directly back without
>   any interference, use the passthru()
>   function.
>        To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the
>   output parameter.

So you have to do something similar to this:

```
<?php
   $output = array();
   $command = "cat /etc/passwd | cut -d\":\" -f1";
   echo 'running the command: <b>'.$command."</b><br />";
   exec($command, &$output);
   echo implode("<br />\n", $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As @benjamin explains, no need to be root or sudo, no need for SUID.
Just pure PHP. I used the field names from [posix_getpwnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php).

```
function getUsers() {
    $result = [];
    /** @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php */
    $keys = ['name', 'passwd', 'uid', 'gid', 'gecos', 'dir', 'shell'];
    $handle = fopen('/etc/passwd', 'r');
    if(!$handle){
        throw new \RuntimeException("failed to open /etc/passwd for reading! ".print_r(error_get_last(),true));
    }
    while ( ($values = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ':')) !== false ) {
        $result[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $result;
}
```

It returns an array containing all users, formatted like this:

```
[
  [
    'name' => 'root',
    'passwd' => 'x',
    'uid' => '0',
    'gid' => '0',
    'gecos' => 'root',
    'dir' => '/root',
    'shell' => '/bin/bash',
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'daemon',
    'passwd' => 'x',
    'uid' => '1',
    'gid' => '1',
    'gecos' => 'daemon',
    'dir' => '/usr/sbin',
    'shell' => '/usr/sbin/nologin',
  ],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Matt S said, that's an incredibly bad idea to allow www-data root access on your server. The slightest compromise through your web applications could allow anyone full control of your system.

A better idea would be to make separate scripts for specific accessions then use [SUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) permissions. This means, a specific user (in this case, www-data) can make small changes to the system through the execution of scripts. Still not a good idea, though. You may be able to work around it with suPHP but security is still a major concern.

Comment: but how I can build a page that can do some system changes?like adding/deleting users / change the ip an the host of the system I will always need som admin poer o do that !!!

Answer (score 0):

/etc/passwd is readable by anyone, so you should be able to execute your command without having any special rights (unless PHP prevents it?).